# Disable "Special Variables" globally, and for all new projects

Tags: python, pycharm

I dislike the "Special Variables" tab, and I've never used it. I disable it with:

```
File > Settings > Build, Execution, ... > Console > Show Console Variables by Default
```

However, it's a setting for "For current project" only. I'm looking for a way to disable it globally, and that it won't be enabled by default for new projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met this in the past.This is my solution:

Try:

```
File > Close Project > Configure(on the left-bottom corner) > Setting > Build, 
    Execution, Deployment. > Console > Show Console Variables by default
```

Comment: Or `File - New Projects Settings - Settings For New Projects...`